# Can I test an Android p2p application using just one phone?

Tags: android, p2p, android-debug

Is there any trick to run two instances of the same app or somethink like this. My phone is not rooted I would not like to root it

Comment: Install one on your phone and run the other from an emulator? That's about your best bet.

Comment: The emulator does not support wifi, and my application is using p2p over wifi direct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was NO. I could not use only one phone to test a P2P application.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml and build a new apk you will be able to install the application twice as the system views them as two separate applications.

Comment: I tried to using a Service in which I called startRegistration() and than from the MainActivity I called discoverService() to find it... but without success (i am refering to the functions startRegistration() and discoverService() defined in this article http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html )

Comment: What device are you testing this on? The Wi-Fi P2P api uses Wifi-Direct and so needs hardware support to function.